# 2 dimension time series groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a transaction table containing:

```
   timestamp, user_id,  val
```

I need to groupby by user_id and apply complex operations on val like

```
   len(val[by_user_id].unique())
```

but, different for each columns....

Which way would be the most efficient ?

1) Split with a loop for on

```
   for x in user_id_list  :
```

or 2) use Pandas groupby, but this is not clear how to apply different functions for each columns....

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) to apply multiple functions at once, either on all columns, or specific per column. You want to do the later. For this pass a dictionary with colum name and function name like below:

```
df.groupby('by_user_id').agg({'val':'min', 'timestamp':'max'})
```

Comment: Instead of 'min', can I use my custom function ?

Comment: Sure, just pass its name without quotes

Comment: Thx, What about creating new colums based on processing of other colums:  'newcol'= my_fun('col1', 'col2')   ?